# Fail to sort nomenclature using prefix

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I'm trying to get my nomenclature to sort alphabetically, including word with accent. Basics! Well, I read all `\nomencl` documentation and many of your expert answers here... 
So I tried different things, inserted a prefix and modified my `build.bat` to run LaTeX, `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.els`, rerun LaTeX, then pdflatex...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[7em]

\nomenclature{déc.}{Décision}
\nomenclature[e]{éd.}{édition}
\nomenclature{Gaz. Pal.}{Gazette du palais}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, it's still not working for me... I'm close to take it personally!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a default prefix `a` that is added before the entries without optional argument.
Therefore `aGaz...` is sorted before `e...`. You can redefine the default prefix to an empty string:

```
\renewcommand*{\nomprefix}{}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! No regret, I wouldn't have found it by myself... Thank you very much for your quick and perfect answer! ;-)